# JSON syntax for Spotify Web API

Tags: json, spotify

I'm using Spotify Web API for a project, but i'm missing something because I get a 400 Error that according to `Documentation` is a syntax problem.

The code is:

```
    function generatePlaylist(access_token) {

        $.ajax({
          url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/playlists',
          method: "POST",
          data: {"name": "New Playlist", "description": "New playlist description","public": false},

          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
          },

            success: function(response) {
                console.log("Success!");
            }
        });
    }
```

It's a novice question, but could anyone help me in writting the correct JSON request? Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, here's the functional code. Just needed to add JSON.stringify:

```
    function generatePlaylist(access_token) {

        $.ajax({
          url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/playlists',
          method: "POST",
          data: JSON.stringify({name: "test", public: false}),

          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
          },

            success: function(response) {
                console.log("Success!");
            }
        });
    }
```